# SharePoint 2010 - Add filter to a list with PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, filter

How it is possible to add a filter to a list with PowerShell?
(I want to add a filter to multiple lists)

Is there any tutorial, articel or example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simply add filter to default view of existing list you can use:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://mysamplesite"
$list = $web.GetList("http://mysamplesite/Lists/mysamplelist")
$query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MyField' /><Value Type='Text'>MyFilterValue</Value></Eq></Where>"    
$view = $list.DefaultView;
$view.Query = $query
$view.Update();
```

You can always use different approach and add new view to list:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://mysamplesite"
$list = $web.GetList("http://mysamplesite/Lists/mysamplelist")
$query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MyField' /><Value Type='Text'>MyFilterValue</Value></Eq></Where>"
$view = $list.DefaultView;
$fields = $list.DefaultView.ViewFields.ToStringCollection()
$list.Views.Add("NewView", $fields, $query, 100, $true, $false)
```

Note: This script copies fields from default view.

This is all just a simple example so feel free to ask additional questions.